Saving an edit to a Mate panel feature or, copy or paste an icon added to the panel?
I edited  some frames from the Internet (cut and attached them) and used them in an existing feature in the Mate panel,  called Fish.
I can't seem to save the customization I made, so I am manually  remaking the edit again and again.
I am sure there is a feature for this I could not find anything though. If anyone knows much appreciated
"edit for Clarification "
each cat added up needs 3 steps creating a fish
changing the file
changing the frame rate then it is added  , if i click on the fish tool again it only restores the default settings , i tried to add the image file inside the files they already provided but could not, so each cat added up needs the same process
i tried to at least copy a panel from the ones i added if i cant save the customisation  in order to recreate it quickly but  did not find any resources about this in all of the tools pages i read
Cats Animation:



Fish:




So, is the issue that you're unable to save the thing you created using the Fish tool, or that you've made some customization to the Fish tool itself, and cannot save THAT, or something else? Please EDIT your post to make it more clear the problem you are facing. Also, please share with us any research you have done and attempts you have made to solve this problem yourself.

if i understood correctly the latter what i made stays on the desktop it is just that i have to remake each one manually and cant use or copy the existing ones
